# TP in MDN Web Docs Browser Compatability Chart

Tags: javascript, browser

In the [Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) MDN Web Docs, the Browser Compatability for Safari is listed as 'TP' in a blue square. What does TP mean?

Comment: i'd assume it's their beta version - equivalent of chrome canary, but i dont think this is the place to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TP stands for ["Technology Preview"](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/), an experimental version of Apple's Safari browser. On the mdn page, there is an `abbr` tag next to TP with a title of *"Preview browser support"*.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here: https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/blob/main/javascript/builtins/Array.json

It says `preview` for Safari, and no support for Safari iOS.